# Extracting IMEI from phone on Android 10 via Knox SDK

Tags: android, imei, samsung-knox

Since Android 10 (API 29), there are no more possibilities to extract IMEI from the phone programmatically by Android API. Is there any way via Samsung Knox SDK API to extract phone IMEI for Android 10?

As android permission "READ_PRIVILEGDE_PHONE_STATE" is required to do so. I did not see Knox API to allow these permissions.

Since system apps are allowed to have "READ_PRIVILEGDE_PHONE_STATE", is there Knox API (or some way) to pronounce our pre installed application (Via Knox profile) as a system app, since I can not find it?

Or is there any other workaround with Knox SDK to extract IMEI from the phone on android 10?

Comment: What's your use case for using KNOX and needing the IMEI? Maybe I can offer a workaround

Comment: Can ou link me about not being able to get IMEI on Android10? I just read the dev note and didnt noticed that

Comment: Marcos, they bring new privacy changes. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids

Comment: Blundell, our case is: Our clients buy Samsung phones with Knox in different countries. We need to programmatically extract unique device identifier from code which can be also seen physically by our clients without turning phone on. (which they get in documentation). IMEI is perfect for this case. Do you have an idea which other identifier could be used for our case to be possible to extract from android 10 version?

Answer (score 0):

Not with the SDK but you can use their (very badly documented) [Open API's.](https://docs.samsungknox.com/admin/knox-manage/list-of-open-api.htm)

You can get the serial number via Knox SDK and send a request to `selectDeviceInfoBySerialNumber` to get very detailed device info which also contains IMEI.